# XSLT - Merge nodes into collection

Tags: xml, xslt

I've the following source data:

```
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
     <ID>28</ID>
     <BRAND>TGR</BRAND>
     <ACC_NO>143080</ACC_NO>
     <ACC_DESCR>account description</ACC_DESCR>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
     <ID>28</ID>
     <BRAND>TGR</BRAND>
     <ACC_NO>272180</ACC_NO>
     <ACC_DESCR>account description</ACC_DESCR>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
     <ID>32</ID>
     <BRAND>TGR</BRAND>
     <ACC_NO>159880</ACC_NO>
     <ACC_DESCR>account description</ACC_DESCR>
  </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

Which i want to transform into:

```
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
     <ID>28</ID>
     <BRAND>TGR</BRAND>
     <ACCOUNTS>
       <ACCOUNT>
         <ACC_NO>143080</ACC_NO>
         <ACC_DESCR>account description</ACC_DESCR>
       <ACCOUNT>
       <ACCOUNT>
         <ACC_NO>272180</ACC_NO>
         <ACC_DESCR>account description</ACC_DESCR>
       <ACCOUNT>
     <ACCOUNTS>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
     <ID>32</ID>
     <BRAND>TGR</BRAND>
     <ACCOUNTS>
       <ACCOUNT>
         <ACC_NO>159880</ACC_NO>
         <ACC_DESCR>account description</ACC_DESCR>
       <ACCOUNT>
     <ACCOUNTS>
  </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

Applying the following transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/DATA/ITEM">
      <ITEM>
        <ID>
          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        </ID>
        <BRAND>
          <xsl:value-of select="BRAND"/>
        <BRAND>
        <ACCOUNTS>
          <ACCOUNT>
            <AccountNumber>
              <xsl:value-of select="ACC_NO"/>
            <AccountNumber>
            <AccountDescription>
              <xsl:value-of select="ACC_DESCR"/>
            <AccountDescription>
          </ACCOUNT>
        </ACCOUNTS>
      </ITEM>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I will get ACCOUNTS list inside ITEM, but still not merging ITEM's with same ID. Basically i'll get always a collection with a single element, instead of all the accounts under same ID.

Any suggestion how can i do it and produce the desired output?

Thanks

Comment: XSLT 1.0 if possible. It is an Oracle SOA Suite project, which doesn't support 2.0 natively. Anyway, there's a small workaround to run 2.0 so if you think it's really helpful i can go for it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you simply replace the outer `for-each` with a `for-each-group` and then add an inner `for-each` to create one `ACCOUNT` per group member:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="/DATA/ITEM" group-by="ID">
      <ITEM>
        <ID>
          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        </ID>
        <BRAND>
          <xsl:value-of select="BRAND"/>
        <BRAND>
        <ACCOUNTS>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <ACCOUNT>
              <AccountNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="ACC_NO"/>
              <AccountNumber>
              <AccountDescription>
                <xsl:value-of select="ACC_DESCR"/>
              <AccountDescription>
            </ACCOUNT>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ACCOUNTS>
      </ITEM>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

In 1.0 the most efficient approach is a technique known as *Muenchian grouping* - define a *key* giving the grouping criteria and then use a trick with `generate-id` to pull out just the first instance of a given ID as a proxy for the group as a whole.

```
<xsl:key name="itemById" match="ITEM" use="ID" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/DATA/ITEM[
          generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemById', ID)[1])]">
      <ITEM>
        <ID>
          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        </ID>
        <BRAND>
          <xsl:value-of select="BRAND"/>
        <BRAND>
        <ACCOUNTS>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('itemById', ID)">
            <ACCOUNT>
              <AccountNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="ACC_NO"/>
              <AccountNumber>
              <AccountDescription>
                <xsl:value-of select="ACC_DESCR"/>
              <AccountDescription>
            </ACCOUNT>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ACCOUNTS>
      </ITEM>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

`key('itemById', ID)[1]` gives you the first `ITEM` element which has the same `ID` value as the current one we're testing, and then comparing the `generate-id` values of the two allows you to determine whether or not they are the same node.

(Personally I would approach the problem using templates rather than `for-each` but the principle remains the same)

Comment: Indeed! :) I was struggling trying to apply templates without success, and because it is not natively supported i'm always forgetting about the potential use of XSLT 2.0. Thanks a lot!